# Access PHP Object on AJAX Parser Page?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using AJAX to submit `POST` data to a parser file

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo AJAX_DIR; ?>/parser.php',
    data: data,
    etc......
```

On the submitting page, I can echo/use `$user->data()->id;` just fine.  If I browse to the parser file directly I can also echo/use `$user->data()->id;` just fine.  However, when I submit the AJAX, the `$user` object is empty.

I've also tried using a `$_SESSION` variable to get my data to the AJAX parser and the same behavior is present (good on the page and parser file when I browse to it, but empty upon AJAX submission).

Any ideas?

**EDIT** for showing the first few lines of the parser file...

```
<?php

//For allowing this to be accessed from anywhere within users.mysite.com
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://users.mysite.com');

//Userspice requires
require_once '../../init.php';
```

Note: The init.php file starts the session as the first thing.

Comment: Can we see your parser.php code. And at first look what i feel is that your parser.php might be looking for a cookie /header in the ajax request which  might be causing the issue. to be clear is the $user object retrieved from session ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027: I edited my post.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show $user line

Comment: @Osama: I'm not sure what you mean.  $user is an object.  OVerall, the issue seems to be that I'm losing the entire session when submitting ajax, but it's fine when I browse to the parser file directly.

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out.  If you are sending ajax from `sub.domain.com` and parsing it at `domain.com/sub/parser.php` it breaks.  I fixed it by telling the ajax submit to parse the info. at `sub.domain.com/parser.php`.

Hope that helps someone else.